# Computing average over different columns/rows in a list of data.frames

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, lapply

I've a list of 140 elements of type data.frame ('my.list'). I would like to compute 350 averages of certain values ranges in a certain column for a certain set of rows in a certain data.frame (this is a bit cryptic); so, 350 different averages like:

- Of data.frame #1, the average of column 'Measure1', row 1:5;
- Of data.frame #2, the average of column 'Measure3', row 1:4, etc. etc.

I have another data.frame ('my.dfAverage') which indicates for which data.frame, column and rows it needs the average. I want to write the 350 different averages and standard deviations to this data.frame (so with the columns: 'average_id', 'dataframe_number', 'column_name', 'row_numbers', 'average' and 'st_dev'). Some value ranges have NA's, these values can be dropped for computing the average.

What is the best way to automatically compute the 350 averages and standard deviations from the list of data.frames based on the info in this data.frame? I thought of creating a for-loop (or maybe the lapply function?), but I'm quite new to these functions, so I'm not sure what the way to go is here.

Small reproducible example of my list of data.frames:

```
my.df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1:5),
                    Measure1 = c(2247,2247,1970,1964,1971),
                    Measure2 = c(2247,2247,NA,1964,1971))
my.df2 <- data.frame(ID = c(1:4),
                    Measure3 = c(2247,NA,1970,1964),
                    Measure5 = c(2247,2247,NA,1964))
my.df3 <- data.frame(ID = c(1:4),
                    Measure6 = c(2247,600,1970,1964),
                    Measure8 = c(2247,2247,NA,1964))

my.list <- list(list1 = my.df1, list2 = my.df2, list3 = my.df3)
```

Desired output table for the averages and standard deviation:

```
my.dfAverage <- data.frame(average_id = c(1:3),
                           dataframe_number = c(1,2,3),
                           column_name = c('Measure1','Measure3','Measure6'),
                           row_numbers = c('1:3','1:4','1:2'),
                           average = (NA),
                           st_dev = (NA))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a different approach than the one given above: I will use only `base r` functions: Point to note, ensure the data has `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`

write a function but ensure you index `mylist` correctly.  then compute  the function on this i e `f(...,na.rm=T)`. to write a function using `apply`:

```
  fun1=function(f){with(my.dfAverage,
   mapply(function(x,y,z)
   f(x[eval(parse(text=y)),z],na.rm=T),my.list,row_numbers,column_name))}

 transform(my.dfAverage,average=fun1(mean),st_dev=fun1(sd))

  average_id dataframe_number column_name row_numbers  average    st_dev
1          1                1    Measure1         1:3 2154.667  159.9260
2          2                2    Measure3         1:4 2060.333  161.6859
3          3                3    Measure6         1:2 1423.500 1164.6049
```

Data Used:

```
my.dfAverage <- data.frame(average_id = c(1:3),
                           dataframe_number = c(1,2,3),
                           column_name = c('Measure1','Measure3','Measure6'),
                           row_numbers = c('1:3','1:4','1:2'),
                           average = (NA),
                           st_dev = (NA),stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution using [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse).

First, expand the `my.dfAverage` based on `row_numbers`.

```
library(tidyverse)

my.dfAverage2 <- my.dfAverage %>%
  separate(row_numbers, into = c("start", "end")) %>%
  mutate(row_numbers = map2(start, end, `:`)) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  select(-start, -end) %>%
  mutate(row_numbers = as.integer(row_numbers),
         dataframe_number = as.integer(dataframe_number))
```

Second, transform all data frames in `my.list` and combine them to a single data frame.

```
my.list.df <- my.list %>%
  setNames(1:length(.)) %>%
  map_dfr(function(x){
  x2 <- x %>%
    gather(column_name, value, -ID)
  return(x2)
},.id = "dataframe_number") %>%
  mutate(ID = as.integer(ID), dataframe_number = as.integer(dataframe_number)) %>%
  rename(row_numbers = ID)
```

Third, merge `my.dfAverage2` and `my.list.df` and calculate the mean and standard deviation. `my.dfAverage3` is the final output.

```
my.dfAverage3 <- my.dfAverage2 %>%
  left_join(my.list.df, by = c("dataframe_number", "column_name", "row_numbers")) %>%
  group_by(average_id, dataframe_number, column_name) %>%
  summarise(row_numbers = paste(min(row_numbers), max(row_numbers), sep = ":"),
            average = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE),
            st_dev = sd(value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup()
my.dfAverage3
# A tibble: 3 x 6
#   average_id dataframe_number column_name row_numbers average st_dev
#        <int>            <int> <chr>       <chr>         <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1          1                1 Measure1    1:3            2155    160
# 2          2                2 Measure3    1:4            2060    162
# 3          3                3 Measure6    1:2            1424   1165
```

**DATA**

`my.list` is the same as OP's `my.list`.

```
my.dfAverage <- data.frame(average_id = c(1:3),
                           dataframe_number = c(1,2,3),
                           column_name = c('Measure1','Measure3','Measure6'),
                           row_numbers = c('1:3','1:4','1:2'))
```